# Configure the Eclipse environment for WildFly project development

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I'm new to the Eclipse IDE and Java, and trying to setup a development + alpha-testing environment for migrating an old project to newer Java + Application Server versions. I have tried a lot, but obviously I'm still doing it wrong.

I apologize for the long post. The core of my question is in the last two paragraphs (the rest are a description of my installation so far, along with some thoughts), you can go straight there if you have no time reading it all.

The application will be running on the WildFly 28 application server. The configuration I made is described below. The description concerns the development + alpha-testing machine, a Windows computer, not the one the product will be running on. Please provide alternative configurations, advice or ideas, if needed, or comment, esp if any of my assumptions were wrong. I have taken the following steps:

- Installed WildFly 28 (unzipped the .zip). This should be similar to the one on the target machine. My intention is to use the plugins of the WildFly installation (under the modules subfolder), and avoid use of external (additional) libraries if possible. They are already there and this may help with version conflicts, and make installation management easier.
- For the above reason I elected to install a SE (not EE) JRE-only Java VM (Eclipse Temurin JRE with Hotspot 17.0.7+7). Again this should be the same as the target machine. Should I install an EE Java VM instead?
- The server is started (manually) for alpha-testing by running a slightly modified version of standalone.bat (under the bin folder) - just added a SET JAVA_HOME= command (in the java VM installer I chose to not set JAVA_HOME env variable, neither add the VM to PATH). This works, the server starts successfully and loads a "Hello World" .war I uploaded. This is how I would like it to be used in the real installation.

I have troubles with the Eclipse environment, more specifically importing the packages. For example, with the `jms` package. This is normally imported in the sources as `javax.jms.*`. However Eclipse won't compile this, because it uses the (preinstalled) JavaSE-17 jdk. To keep working I added the jakarta.jms-api-3.1.0.jar from deep within the WildFly modules folder to the Java Build Path (as an External JAR) and changed the source to `import jakarta.jms.*` instead. I think this is not only inefficient though (will have to do so for every such plugin I will need to use), it also requires changing the sources to non-standard package names, and most importantly I'm not sure if and what the server will use at run-time. Searched the Wildfly installation folders and found a file named module.xml, under the C:\WF28\modules\system\layers\base\javax\jms\api\main folder, which contains a module alias:

```
<module-alias name="javax.jms.api" target-name="jakarta.jms.api" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.9"/>
```

My understanding is that the server will load the jakarta.jms.api module, if the application requests the javax.jms.api one.

The question is how to tell Eclipse to actually use the server configuration (C:\WF28\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml or standalone-full.xml) for the packages, without having to add the individual .JARs to the Build Path, and using the standard names (eg javax.jms.*). That is, Eclipse should be reading the configuration .xml, determine which modules will be available, and resolve the aliases such as the one in the previous paragraph for source editing + building - this last one is what Eclipe and the compiler appears to NOT be doing. Is this possible? If not please suggest an alternative solution (I would prefer to use SE java VM, for the reasons I described above).

P.S. I have tried adding a server to Eclipse (Window->Show View->Other->Server..) but this didn't help. Also tried adding an External Class Folder to the Build Path (C:\WF28\modules\system\layers\base) and didn't help either (it doesn't contain .jar files, it contains a set of module.xml files), it appears this is not taken into account neither by Eclipse (source editing, although code completion works) nor by the compiler.

Comment: Did you install the JBoss Tools or other plug-ins to support launching WildFly? It sounds like you're doing a lot of what those tools handle manually.

Comment: Are you using Maven or some other build tool like Gradle?

Comment: @nitind, thanks for your suggestion. I haven't installed JBoss Tools or such plugins yet. I'm nowhere close to running the app or even deploying it. For the moment I have to get the app built first. Unless this also helps with the development/refactoring phase, I would rather postpone it. But as I will need to install them anyway, I installed them just now. Can this help in this phase?

Comment: @James R. Perkins, thank you too. No, this is a simple new project, which I created and started throwing the old sources in. Can these tools help solve the specific issue I described in the post? I can't make Eclipse/compiler capable of resolving package names yet.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Yes, it should help with development, probably beyond simply getting the project classpath correct. You probably need to work in a dynamic web project, though, as you haven't mentioned anything about it other than Java.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Eclipse these days, but IMO it's always better to use a standard build tool over an IDE build. It doesn't limit you to a specific IDE and allows for CI runs.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Indeed, ideally it should compile using just javac. It was an ant project actually. However, using an IDE is convenient, because of goodies like code completion and online syntax checks, esp useful for an old project like this, with so many libraries and even standard java modules having dramatically changed since it was originally developed. It was an ant-based project, and working with a generic editor like Notepad++ and attempting to build it only to see javac stopping at the first few errors is a torture and absolutely unproductive. No IDE-specific source changes of course.

Comment: All Java IDE's I'm aware of work with build tools like Maven, Gradle, Ivy, etc. If you're migrating a project I would highly recommend you use a build tool. You can still use an IDE, I do all the time, but it's much more portable to use a build tool.